# PopEnter animation not working in Navigation component

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I would like to make slide transition in both ways between two fragments. What i have done is working now in enter animation and popExit, not popEnter(previous fragment shows without transition).

My transition action looks like this:

```xml
<action 
   android:id="@+id/action_welcomeFragment_to_interfaceScalePickFragment"
   app:destination="@id/interfaceScalePickFragment"
   app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
   app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
   app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
   app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />
```

One of my custom animations looks like that(it's slide_out_left)

```xml
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate android:duration="500" android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"/>
    <alpha android:duration="500" android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" />
</set>
```

And my, for example, welcome fragment is written like this:

```kotlin
package com.delet_dis.elementarylauncher.fragments

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import com.delet_dis.elementarylauncher.R
import com.delet_dis.elementarylauncher.databinding.FragmentWelcomeScreenBinding

class WelcomeFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentWelcomeScreenBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            binding = FragmentWelcomeScreenBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

            binding.root
        } else {
            view
        }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            binding.getStartedButton.setOnClickListener {
                requireActivity().findNavController(R.id.fragmentContainerView)
                    .navigate(R.id.action_welcomeFragment_to_interfaceScalePickFragment)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to rewrite project in Canary version(because recently the host was not displayed in the release version, but everything worked in canary).

I also tried to replace first fragment(welcome) with studio-built fragment, the error in the absence of animation is repeated

Comment: I just updated the gradle dependencies and got the same issues. The culprit is fragment-ktx, went back to version 1.3.1 for now.

Comment: @Sourabh It solved my problem. Thank you

Comment: Seems like it's a bug in `androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.2`: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/183877426